# Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.NETCore.App'

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

I've upgraded from .NET Core 2.0 to 2.1.1 (so many elements that gets highly confusing).

I built my project and now I'm getting this error:

> Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.NETCore.App'

I don't know what other information should I provide. Please guide me in providing more info on this issue.

It's such a frustrating experience. Upgrading **backward compatible version** in [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) shouldn't break things. I wish they had versioned this release as .NET Core 3.0, so that we wouldn't upgrade. Any help?

**Update**: I created [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1725).

Answer (score 3):

I did simple fix for this issue, I selected option to  **remove additional files at destination** before publish and then it solved my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just set **MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish** to **false** in your .csproj file and that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the [SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows). Download and install 2.1.301 (at the time of writing), and you'll be okay. FWIW, you're not *forced* to upgrade. If the packages upgraded automatically, you either set a wildcard on package version or you just did something like "Upgrade all" in the NuGet Package Manager GUI. If you're concerned about things upgrading without your permission, then use explicit version numbers and pick and choose each package to upgrade manually.

Comment: I downloaded the exact same SDK. Didn't solve my problem. In fact, I had downloaded the exact same SDK before asking this question.

Comment: Also, all of my packages use specific version. I hate wildcards when managing dependencies. I prefer to know what I'm eating rather than eating whatever that might come.

Comment: That error is pretty telling. For some reason it's not seeing your SDK. Are you sure you didn't just install the runtime? Not trying to insult your intelligence, but like I said, the error really only means one thing.

Comment: Even if you insult my intelligence, I accept that if it solves my problem. What I do always, is to go to [dotnet download page that contains all of the downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all), and download the `current` version. I checked it once more and saw that the version I downloaded is `2.1.301`. Then I of course download SDK, because that's what developers download to build applications, not just in dotnet, but also in Android, and other environments. I also downloaded the runtime and installed that too but no result.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your hosted folder and install fresh. Re-installing the SDK/runtimes did not fully correct the issue for me.

Resolved this error by:

1. Re/Install SDK on IIS Server (2.1.3xx)
2. Re/Install SDK on Dev Machine (2.1.3xx)
3. Re/Install Runtime on IIS Server (2.1.2)
4. Clean hosted folder on IIS Server (I had old cshtml/dlls)
5. Republish to clean folder

Also try with an empty new project (File -> New Project -> ASP.NET Core Web Site -> 2.1)